# Objective-C: Point of releasing a View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, release

I made a static mainmenu with a TableView. Sometimes it crashes because my Subview has allready deallocated a subview.

Is also ok to release a View in the dealloc method of the local object instead of that:

```
[NavController pushViewController:self.AnotherView animated:YES];
[self.AnotherView release]; //This line into (void)viewDidLoad
```

AnotherView is defined in the headerfile as property and also synchronozed in the .m-File

When i use the dealloc way it works great on the device, but I need to know if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call release for objects you `init` or `alloc` yourself. If it is a property of your class then `release` in the `dealloc` of your class.

So in your case, unless you `init` `anotherView` a few lines above your sample code (same method), calling `release` on it where you are is going to cause a leak/SIG_ABORT because you have done so prematurely.

Feel free to post more code, particularly how anotherView is assigned and you may get a more specific answer.

Comment: release will cause a double free, not a leak.

Comment: True. I was trying to get at the error Simon was receiving. But yet, this was a premature release. TWSS